# Liferay grid structure, make equal width rows

Tags: gridview, grid, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

How can I make 5 equal width rows with grid? When I set my grid - number of modules to be 5, third row in the middle is wider than the others? Is there any way to set five equal width rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay's grid is based on bootstrap, which provides a virtual grid of 12 possible columns - this way you'll have the option to have fractions like 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/6, and 1/12 as the width for a row. 1/5 is not among the options, so you'll have to change at least one row's width (and the grid is flexible, so that you can also change the width of two of two rows)